# How to output tables using Oracle PL/SQL utl_smtp.write_data(conn, mesg);

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am looking for a way to output tables using Oracle PL/SQL `utl_smtp.write_data(conn, mesg);`

I could assume a fixed width font on the email client side and print using something like this:

```
|---|
| a |
|---|
```

Or I could assume HTML capabilities. Either way this might not be a valid assumption and I'm not sure how to output html using utl_smtp. Anyone have some code that can solve this conundrum?

Comment: There used to be a package called `DEMO_MAIL` on OTN but I can't find it...
If you could find it, it's very usefull

Comment: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1739411218448

Comment: maybe use email attachments instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to guarantee the format of rendered text is to send it as a PDF attachment.  So use plain test: just warn the recipient that layout might get mangled in a proportional font:

```
utl_smtp.open_data(l_mail_conn);  
utl_smtp.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'For best results view this with a fixed font'|| utl_tcp.crlf);  
utl_smtp.write_data(l_mail_conn,'|---|' || utl_tcp.crlf);
utl_smtp.write_data(l_mail_conn,'| a |' || utl_tcp.crlf);
utl_smtp.write_data(l_mail_conn,'|---|' || utl_tcp.crlf);
utl_smtp.close_data(l_mail_conn);
```

Well, that's the principle.  Obviously, in real-life you would build a wrapping procedure and perhaps call it in a loop.

If you want to use HTML instead, Tom Kyte has posted a procedure which does it.  [Find it here.](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11%3a%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1739411218448)